# Is there any way to open/initialize a separate respository for a subfolder in VS Code without VS Code detecting the repo in the parent directory?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, version-control

I'm working on an extension for another project. As such, my project folder is within the directory `./extensions/my_extension relative` to the original project. But as I cloned the original project from GitHub, VSCode recognizes it when I'm working in the subfolder.

### Method 1

Initially, I set up a code-workspace with two folders open, the main project and my extension. But VSCode automatically opens the original project's repository in Source Control. I was able to close it, but VSCode still detects it:

[image: Reopen Closed Respoitory]

### Method 2

So, I tried opening my folder by itself, revealing this:

[image: A git respository was found in the parent folders]

As you can see, I set the setting to "never" and have restarted it twice, but it still prompts me to open the parent respository.

*(Note that I have restarted VSCode three times via Task Manager and restarted my computer after trying each method)*

Of course, I understand that I am able to copy my extension folder into a separate folder, but it eventually gets annoying after doing it every time I save a file.

Comment: is your project in the folder with VSC extensions

Comment: when you are developing an extension you don't need the parent repo, clone the parent project a second time in a new folder `extdev`, remove the project `.git` folder and develop and create your extension repo in the correct location you want

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you for the response.
I don't think I understand what you mean. Would it be possible for you to create an answer with step-by-step instructions? My goal is to close the parent repo and open mine, but I need to have my project in the parent directory, which VSCode doesn't seem to allow. And I cannot find any .git in the parent directory.

Edit: I found the .git folder, it was hidden. I will update you on how it goes.

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you! Changing the name of the parent folder after removing the .git folder allowed me to initialize a repository. But do you know of any way to delete it manually so I don't need to clone/rename the folder?